# MySQL Combining data from columns with identical names

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables that each have a column with the same name (is_featured). I'm trying to select and display the item_name from these two identical 'is_featured' columns and sort by date desc.

VIDEOS

```
            item_name  |  is_featured  |  date     |  item_active

            item a     |  yes          |  1-1-13   |  1
            item b     |  no           |  1-13-13  |  1
            item c     |  yes          |  1-3-13   |  1
```

PHOTOS

```
            item_name  |  is_featured  |  date     |  item_active

            item d     |  no           |  2-1-13   |  1
            item e     |  no           |  1-2-13   |  1
            item f     |  yes          |  1-19-13  |  1
```

I tried using a UNION query with these two tables, but I can't figure out how to sort the combined results by date.

```
(SELECT item_name FROM Videos WHERE item_active=1 ORDER BY date DESC)
UNION
(SELECT item_name FROM Photos WHERE item_active=1 ORDER BY date DESC)
```

What am I missing? Is UNION the incorrect approach?

Comment: Why do you think you're missing something?

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong datetime format. Union query is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort after creating the union.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT item_name, date
      FROM Videos
      WHERE item_active = 1
      UNION
      SELECT item_name, date
      FROM Photos
      WHERE item_active = 1) x
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: MySQL requires subqueries to have an alias, even if you don't use it.

Comment: So if I put that query in an $sql variable, would I call the data like this? $result = $this->query($sql);
if($result) {
while($row = $this->fetchAssoc($result)) {
echo $row['x'] . "<br />\n";
}
}

Comment: Disregard previous question, I tweaked it with this: echo $row['item_name'] . "<br />\n";  That's what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand your overall problem but if sorting is just the issue then try:-

```
select item_name,date from (
(SELECT item_name, data FROM Videos WHERE item_active=1 )
UNION
(SELECT item_name, date FROM Photos WHERE item_active=1 )
) a
order by a.date desc
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a unique alias on the item_name of each table so that I can add identifiers to the data when it's called. For example: item_names will have either a 'photo' or 'video' class assigned to it. So basically, I need some kind of logic that checks if this item_name came from Videos, add this class, and vice versa.

Comment: yes of course. try this:-
select item_name, class,date from (
(SELECT item_name, 'video' class,date FROM Videos WHERE item_active=1 )
UNION
(SELECT item_name, 'photo' class, date FROM Photos WHERE item_active=1 )
) a
order by a.date desc